# Vuetify Typography Not Found text-h1 CSS

Tags: vue.js, text, material-design, vuetify.js, typography

I've Copy the VuetifyDemo's View source to My Project,But it's not work.
vueControl the size and style of text using the Typography helper classes.
But My Vuetify's Project has not found the Typography helper class,such as text-h1 text-xl-h2...
Do not know whether I missing someone installer step?

Demo URL: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/text-and-typography/typography.

Comment: For the future, what version were you running originally before upgrade? The one that did not work?

Answer (score 1):

it's Work when I upgrade to Vuetify@2.3.4